# aligning images using HTML

Tags: html, image, web, google-web-designer

I'm currently trying to design a web page. I don't have much experience with HTML and are therefore finding it difficult to get my page looking how i'd planned. I would like to have four square images, two top with two directly below but im struggling to align these. I've tried to research this but all i seem to be able to find are examples with text wrap. 
any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: share some code please

Answer (score 0):

Are your images of the same size ?

Without more information on what you want/have on your page, it's kind of hard to know what you need.
But here's an simple example : http://codepen.io/cecileledoux/pen/mWJyGV

```
<section>
    <figure>
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="" />
     </figure>
</section>
<section>
    <figure>
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="" />
     </figure>
</section>

section{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
figure{
     display: inline-block;
}
```